# Add JSON object to multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, winjs

My aim is to add a JSON object based on certain conditions to an array which is then to be used to construct a WINJSList. I'm really struggling with accessing the elements of the list OR array after I have used the array.push method. I wanted to access these elements to ensure I am doing the addition right. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have the following code

```
var names_Array = new Array;                
var names_List = new WinJS.Binding.List(names_Array);

if (condition) {
  if (condition) {
    names_List.push({ 
      name: "Joe Dowling", 
      image: "image/Joe Dowling.png", 
      ClientID: "1234" 
    });
  } else if (condition) {
    names_List.push({
      name: "Esteban Flamenco ", 
      image: "image/Esteban Flamenco.png", 
      ClientID: "6666" 
    });
  } else if (condition) {
    names_List.push({ 
      name: "Plain Jane ", 
      image: "image/Plain Jane.png", 
      ClientID: "0000" 
    });
                        }
console.log(names_Array);
console.log(names_Array[0]);
console.log(names_List);
console.log(names_List[0]);
```

I also tried:

```
var names_Array = new Array; 
if (condition) { 
  if (condition) {
    names_Array.push({
      name: "Joe Dowling", 
      image: "image/Joe Dowling.png", 
      ClientID: "1234" 
    });
  } else if (condition) {
    names_Array.push({
      name: "Esteban Flamenco ", 
      image: "image/Esteban Flamenco.png", 
      ClientID: "6666" 
    });
  } else if (condition) {
    names_Array.push({ 
      name: "Plain Jane ", 
      image: "image/Plain Jane.png", 
      ClientID: "0000" 
    });
  }

  var names_List = new WinJS.Binding.List(names_Array);
```

In the console I either get undefined or [object object]

Comment: Note in both examples you have syntax errors, I assume this is because you're not showing us actual representations of your real code. This makes it more difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: @ JaredMcAteer the condition which I have left out is rather hefty. I know the conditions are correct though because I'm printing it to the console and If I were to delete the names_array.pushes for all the conditions and add console.logs I get what I expect, if that makes any sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For WinJS.Binding.List, refer documention [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700774.aspx).

There are couple of issues with code:

- WinJS List initializes itself with the array passed to the constructor. After that if the array is modified, changes do not propogate to the winjs list.
- To access element at index, use `list.getAt(index)`

this code should work:

```
var data = []; 
data.push({
    name: "Joe Dowling",
    image: "image/Joe Dowling.png",
    ClientID: "1234"
});
data.push({
    name: "Esteban Flamenco ",
    image: "image/Esteban Flamenco.png",
    ClientID: "6666"
        });
data.push({
    name: "Plain Jane ",
    image: "image/Plain Jane.png",
    ClientID: "0000"
});

var list = new WinJS.Binding.List(data);
var item = list.getAt(0);
console.info(JSON.stringify(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making this harder than what it should be here is a simple example based on the data you are using :

```
var data = []; 
data.push({ 
      name: "Joe Dowling", 
      image: "image/Joe Dowling.png", 
      ClientID: "1234" 
    });
data.push({
      name: "Esteban Flamenco ", 
      image: "image/Esteban Flamenco.png", 
      ClientID: "6666" 
    });
data.push({ 
      name: "Plain Jane ", 
      image: "image/Plain Jane.png", 
      ClientID: "0000" 
    });


<!-- var item = data.getAt(0) -->
console.info(JSON.stringify(data))
console.info(JSON.stringify(data[0]))
var c = data[0];

for(var i in c){
    console.log(i); //key
    console.log(c[i]); //value
}
```